# PIN Junction Diodes

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Mathematically how do we prove that there is more electron-hole pair recombination happening in the depletion region of PIN diodes when compared to PN diodes?

I’m looking for a specific equation involving Recombination rate in the depletion region for PIN diodes and PN diodes so I can plug in values to prove that recombination is indeed higher in PIN diodes

Comment: Is it necessarily? The volume of the depletion + intrinsic region is larger. What all carriers are you considering?

Comment: I am considering the electron and hole carriers. How do I quantitatively show that there is more recombination happening in the depletion region of PIN diode as opposed to PN diodes? I am looking for the recombination rate equation to prove this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the recombination rate for PIN junction diode

Comment: Under forward bias, or no bias?

Comment: It is under Forward Bias